# Videos in Epiphany problem

Tags: release-loki, epiphany, web-browser

Am I the only one having this problem or is it a bug? Facebook, or youtube, or whatever videos in Epiphany stop playing after a few seconds, freezes, that is, except for the sound that goes until the end. It doesn't happen in Firefox for the same videos. It happens for some time now, I was hoping for an update to fix it, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It's been noted](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=183085), but it seems to be a problem in GStreamer, and the version of GStreamer in Loki is so old that the relevant developer is not interested in debugging it. So we seem to be out of luck.

Comment: Is it just me or is it unclear whether this issue will be solved in Juno?

Comment: It's definitely solved upstream. I can't make any specific promises about the software versions to be included in Juno, because I'm not an elementary developer, but I assume it should be fine there.