# Video freezes when watching videos

Tags: release-loki, release-juno, firefox, epiphany, web-browser

When i watch videos on youtube using firefox or Epiphany the video freezes when i do nothing for a few minutes and i have to move the mouse so that the video continues it's a very annoying problem if you know the solution your answer is appreciated.

I think this person is having the same problem 
[video freezing when do nothing for a few minutes](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/17064/video-freezing-when-do-nothing-for-a-few-minutes)

and this person [Videos in Epiphany problem](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/15020/videos-in-epiphany-problem) this person is using loki so this problem is in loki and juno as far as i know.

Comment: I'm afraid this is a duplicate of: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16700/video-on-chrome-freezing/17311#17311

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issues on two different computers, one with Intel HD4400 and one with Intel HD620 CPU/GPU.
This is how I resolve the problem:

1. Install Updated Open Graphics Drivers PPA

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`

   `sudo apt update`

This will update your Mesa graphics drivers but most importantly your `xserver-xorg-video-*` driver.
A note of caution: It's been known for these drivers to have some issues so I would suggest that after the update, if everything works, remove this PPA from your sources list.

2. Create `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` file with this content:

   Section "Device"

   ```
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"

   Driver      "intel"

   Option      "AccelMethod"    "sna"

   Option      "DRI"            "3"

   Option      "TearFree"       "true"

   Option      "Backlight"      "intel_backlight"
   ```

   EndSection
3. Install `mpv` Media Player. Not `gnome-mpv` but `mpv`. Use this for playing your local videos.

The 1. and 2. did manage to remove all my video-in-browser troubles, I even get to have hardware acceleration in Google Chrome without any issues. Number 3. helped me with the local video files.

There is a good reading on this here: [IntelQuickSyncVideo](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IntelQuickSyncVideo)

---

In case you don't have the command `add-apt-repository`

Run:

`sudo apt install software-properties-common`

and then redo the previous command who contains `add-apt-repository`

Comment: Please note that that intel.conf can cause issues. See the relevant open issue: https://github.com/elementary/os/issues/121

Comment: this solution increased CPU load unfortunately. we need more efficient fix

Comment: @pole I mentioned in my post that this is something that helped me on two different configurations, not to be a universal fix.
The CPU load while playing 4K video on a laptop is around 20% and on my PC below 15%.

Thank you very much for lowering my reputation, you are the man.

Comment: Instead of removing the PPA after the installation (which leaves the installed packages without a corresponding repository) you could also "hold" the packages or use apt pinning. See the Ubuntu Community Wiki for an intro with examples: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto